# Reabrir pergunta sobre algoritmo genético

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Queria debater acerca dessa pergunta: [NullPointerException - Algoritmo Genético](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226404/132)

Atualmente, essa pergunta está fechada como "não está clara o suficiente". Como ela foi postada inicialmente, de fato, ela não estava clara, mas esse problema já foi (na minha opinião) corrigido por meio de edições na pergunta. Uma vez que acredito que este problema está corrigido, gostaria de solicitar a sua reabertura. Não vou entrar no mérito dos votos contrários recebidos. Caso alguém tenha alguma razão para mantê-la fechada, gostaria de debater isso.

Em especial, tenho interesse em postar uma resposta, que inclusive já tenho redigida por completo, só estou aguardando a reabertura para postá-la.

Comment: Este comentário na pergunta é gerado automaticamente pelo sistema?

Comment: @LINQ Não. Eu que postei lá.

Comment: Já votei reabertura, são 4 votos totalizados, só falta mais um.

Comment: Só uma **opinião**, acho que seria interessante colocar alguma frase (o próprio AP), pelo menos falando que queria ajuda para fazer seja lá o que ele queira. Da maneira que está (somente com os códigos e a exceção) *"aparenta"* que é uma pergunta do tipo façam para mim. **Opnião2:** Pode ser isso que atraiu *downvotes* e fechamento, da maneira que foi *"redigida"*.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis Considerando que a pergunta tem bastante código e o código está bem desenvolvido e completo, não é um caso de façam para mim.  O problema que atraiu tantos votos negativos e de fechamento era porque na versão inicial, o autor da pergunta tinha apenas colocado código lá sem dizer o que queria e nem qual era o erro. Apenas na revisão 3 é que o autor postou um stacktrace do erro. Pode-se argumentar que o autor da pergunta não soube se expressar direito, e eu concordaria, mas mesmo assim dá para se entender o que é que ele quer e se perceber que é uma pergunta legítima mesmo assim.

Comment: Reaberta, dei o 5º voto

Comment: @bfavaretto Muito obrigado. Postei lá a resposta. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Muito obrigado a todos. A pergunta foi reaberta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu admiro o esforço que você teve para responder a pergunta.

Ela melhorou, e de fato após certa edição do autor ela deixou de ser certamente obscura para ser clara (apenas) o suficiente. Mas ainda há alguns poréns.

- **A pergunta ainda é um pouco confusa.** O autor fala de algoritmos genéticos no título e nas tags, mas o problema não tem nada a ver com isso. Por esse motivo eu removi as tags de inteligência artificial. Caso alguém ache que elas devem ficar lá, é só recuperar as tags [inteligência-artificial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intelig%c3%aancia-artificial) e [algoritmo-genético](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo-gen%c3%a9tico).
- **A resposta é principalmente um refactoring do código original.** Eu quase tive a impressão de que a pergunta deveria ter sido fechada como *"ampla demais"* ao ver isso.
- **É pouco provável que a pergunta ajude outras pessoas.** Como o problema principal do autor é código mal escrito, a principal solução para ele é rever erros pontuais de lógica. Dificilmente alguém com dúvidas sobre algoritmos genéticos terá exatamente os mesmos erros e será ajudado por essa pergunta.

Eu acho que essa pergunta seria mais adequada para um equivalente em português do [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), caso tivéssemos um. Na falta dele, acho que a pergunta não se encaixa muito bem no SO. Na forma como está nesse momento, eu teria votado para fechar com o seguinte motivo:

> **Fora de escopo ->** Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Mas o sistema não me permite votar para fechá-la neste momento.

Eu acredito que por mais que o autor da pergunta seja inexperiente, seguir as recomendações do link sobre *MCVE* teriam ajudado a corrigir os problemas de lógica.

Comment: Discordo. Acho que code review faz parte do escopo do SOpt sim, apenas temos poucas perguntas por aqui nesse sentido (mas já vi algumas). Depois, não era erro de digitação, e sim alguns erros de lógica mais complexa. O código estava quase completo (só esqueceu das instruções `package`, `import`s e fecha chaves no final das classes). Completando o código manualmente (ruim, mas não vou apedrejar um usuário novato por um detalhe bobo desse), ele se torna reproduzível (tanto é que eu reproduzi) e verificável. Não era mínimo, mas não era nada grande também. Assim sendo, considero válido.

Comment: Quanto a não ajudar ninguém no futuro, eu discordo porque eu sou uma das pessoas que vai ser ajudada no futuro. O código que o OP deu vai me servir para resolver um outro problema que tenho, me poupando o trabalho de ter que codificar toda a estrutura de um algoritmo genético, sobrando para mim apenas fazer o algoritmo do cálculo de fitness do meu problema em particular. É por isso que eu tinha tanto interesse nesta pergunta e me esforcei em respondê-la mais do que faria normalmente. :)